# JSPDF not printing correctly, Blank pdf is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, jspdf

We are using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) in aspnet core app. Here is the scripts section:

```
@section Scripts{

    <script src="~/lib/jsPDF/jspdf.min.js" type="text/javascript" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jsPDF/split_text_to_size.js" type="text/javascript" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jsPDF/standard_fonts_metrics.js" type="text/javascript" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/jsPDF/html2canvas.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jsPDF/html.js" type="text/javascript" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <script src="~/js/dailyjobreport.js" type="text/javascript" asp-append-version="true"></script>

}
```

The html is received from AJAX call, and is used for pdf rendering

```
function onSuccess(data) {
        try {
            var pdf = new jsPDF({
                orientation: 'portrait',
                format: 'a4'
            });

            pdf.html(data);
            pdf.save('report.pdf');
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
}
```

The pdf that is rendered is a balnk page. Can anyone please help find us what's wrong with the code or if we are missing something

Answer (score 0):

Try to use callback function to save to pdf :

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

Js function :

```
$(function () {
    var pdf = new jsPDF({
        orientation: 'portrait',
        format: 'a4'
    });


    pdf.html("<html><head></head><body><h2>2asdasda123dsdasd</h2></body></html>", {
        callback: function (pdf) {
            pdf.save('test.pdf');
        }
    });

})
```